# Is it possible to signal yourself in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, signals

I know it's possible to send `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, etc. to your own process in the C programming language:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signaling-Yourself.html

Does Node.js provide this functionality?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @mscdex: This would be helpful if I want to gracefully shut down the application after some event, and I don't have direct access to the signal handler.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`process.kill(process.pid, "SIGINT");`

`process.kill` sends a signal (`SIGINT` in this case, provided by the second parameter), to a provided PID. (`process.pid` in this case, which is the PID of the running node process.)

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this. It works for me. The next question, how to stop debugging? E.g. stop listening and drop attached debuggers?