# How to support default ^Z behavior in a node program that detects key presses?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I've created a node.js program that gets keypress input from `stdin` by using `setRawMode(true)`, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12506613/4633828). I've already made it so `^C` and `^D` (control-C/control-D) are handled; the code basically looks like this:

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
  if (Buffer.from([0x03]).equals(data) || Buffer.from([0x04]).equals(data)) {
    process.exit()
  }
})
```

It's quite easy to fake how `^C` and `^D` work simply by, well,  causing the program to exit. But how can I make `^Z` work? Obviously I can't *fake* it, because it's something bash normally deals with itself. Is there some way to tell bash/sh/whatever to put the program into the background, the way ^Z normally works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2112/125775) on the Unix & Linux StackExchange was useful. We need to [send a signal to our own process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401640/4633828) - particularly `SIGTSTP`:

```
process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTSTP');
```

Within the context of my program, I also had to clean up any terminal changes (e.g. hiding cursor, using the alternate screen) before sending `SIGTSTP`; and I had to re-apply them upon receiving `SIGCONT`:

```
process.on('SIGCONT', () => {
  process.stdout.write(...);
});
```

I also found that `process.stdin.setRawMode` needed a refresh on `SIGCONT`, for some reason:

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(false);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
```

Comment: For reference, here's my diff implementing this: https://notabug.org/towerofnix/mtui/commit/6da245d2d0a55f64caaf2bb185b343d4f227d0c3